# Можно ли создать DLL используя Qt статической сборки?

Tags: qt5, dll, static

Имеется Qt 5.6.2 статической сборки. Необходимо создать динамическую библиотеку DLL используя эту сборку. 
Проблема заключается в том что например при использовании функции `QMessageBox::about` выдается ошибка:

> undefined reference to `QMessageBox::about(QWidget*, QString const&,
>   QString const&)'

Вот пример:
**.pro**

```
QT       += gui
TARGET = injectDLLm
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += dll

DEFINES += INJECTDLLM_LIBRARY
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += injectdllm.cpp
HEADERS += injectdllm.h\
        injectdllm_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "injectdllm.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>

InjectDLLm::InjectDLLm()
{
    QMessageBox::about(NULL,"Title", "text");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте в pro-файле заменить

```
QT += gui
```

на

```
QT += gui widgets
```

Comment: Спасибо. Немного сглупил я...